# How to create kubernetes custom resources or custom plugin?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-deployment, kubernetes-custom-resources

Whenever the deployment has been created needs to trigger a custom function or webhook. Does Kubernetes provide any option to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Custom Resources are an extension to the Kubernetes API. Just having them standalone is not going to do anything functionally for you. If you need to perform a specific action upon change or deployment or bare existence of a given custom resource, you will need a custom controller that does that.

One of the possible implementations is an Operator. I specifically mention that, as it is fairly easy to create the controller alongside the custom resource definition using [Operator SDK](https://sdk.operatorframework.io/). However you can *just* create a custom resource definition and deploy a [custom controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/#custom-controllers).

On a closing note: there are other ways your question is very broadly formulated so there is a vast variety of ways to answer, and this is just one option.